# Como saber si es vacio o null on campo por ID en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo esto:

```
<select id="division" multiple="multiple" title="Equipos seleccionados" style="width:143px;height:125px;overflow:scroll;">
<option value="1" title="Bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>
</select>
```

Estoy haciendole esto:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function hideFields() {
    var control = findcontrol("equipo");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}

function showFields() {
    var control = findcontrol("equipo");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}

function findcontrol(field) {
    var arr = document.getElementById(field);
    return arr;
}

var values = document.getElementById('division').val();;
if (values != null || values != ''){
    showFields();
}
```

pero no me pasa a la funcion `showFields();`

Lo que quiero es que cuando no haya nada en `division` que no me muestre el `equipo` y cuando si hay algo en `division` que aparezca el `equipo`

Como lo hago en Javascript?
Javascript sin ninguna libreria. El codigo es generado por Sharepoint

Visualmente:

- Al cargar la pagina por defecto

[image: Al cargar la pagina por defecto]

- Al pasar una division a la parte derecha o seleccionarla

[image: Al pasar una division a la parte derecha o seleccionarla]

Comment: ¿Ese es el `<select>` o una porción? ¿Dónde está el código de la función `showFields()` y desde dónde se llama?

Comment: `"equipo"` nunca será igual a null o vacío porque `"equipo"` es un `string` cuyo contenido es la palabra "equipo". Tendrías que ponerlo con js o jquery, es decir `$("#equipo")` o `document.getElementById("equipo")`

Comment: y `OR` no existe en js, `||` es el *operador O logico*

Comment: que es "division", un `<select>` ?

Comment: "division" es un multiple choices

Comment: ¿Quieres saber si se ha seleccionado una de las opciones o si no hay ninguna seleccionada? ¿Sueles marcar alguna como `selected` o siempre dejas el desplegable sin ninguna opción por defecto? Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte :)

Comment: Tienes que entender que el concepto de "esté vacío el select" es ambiguo. Debes especificarnos (en lenguaje natural si lo deseas) cuándo debe llamarse a `showFields();`.

Comment: Empieza vacio sin ninguna opcion seleccionada por defecto, por eso nada mas empezar llamo a la funcion hideFields() y en cuanto el usuario haya seleccionado alguna opcion que aparezca y con el if lo comprueba y que llame a la funcion showFields()

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para tener en cuenta tu última edición.

Comment: Creo que deberías agregar también el `<select>` de la selección, ya que es el que necesitamos validar para hacer aparecer el equipo o no.

Comment: al ser varias opciones, tengo dos cuadrados (izq aparecen opciones, derecha aparecen seleccionados) y agregar/quitar para ir pasando de un cuadrado a otro. la division es la id del cuadro derecha, que son los seleccionados. no se si me explico... es decir, como no hay ninguna division que haya seleccionado al principio el usuario, no aparecen los equipos pero en cuanto pase alguno al cuadrado de la derecha dejara de estar vacio y quiero que aparezcan los equipos de esa division

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti a ver si mi última edición te es de utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta respuesta tiene ediciones sucesivas debido a las ediciones de la respuesta en la que se han ido facilitando más datos:

- [Primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/158721/1) - [primera respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/158745/1).
- [Segunda pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/158721/6) - [segunda respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/158745/3).
- Revisión actual (sin enlaces).

Editado para tener en cuenta tu última edición:

```
var values = document.getElementById('division').val();
if (values != null || values != ''){
    showFields();
}
```

El método [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) no existe en un nodo del DOM del documento HTML, sólo en jQuery. En ese caso el resultado es una matriz con todos y cada uno de los elementos seleccionados:

> When the first element in the collection is a `select-multiple` (i.e., a `select` element with the `multiple` attribute set), `.val()` returns an array containing the value of each selected `option`. As of **jQuery 3.0**, if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to **jQuery 3.0**, it returns `null`.

En castellano:

> Cuando el primer elemento de la colección es un `select-multiple` (p.e., un elemento `select` con el atributo `multiple` activado), `.val()` devuelve una matriz que contiene el valor de cada `option` seleccionada. A partir de **jQuery 3.0**, si no hay opciones seleccionadas devolverá una matriz vacía; previo a **jQuery 3.0** devolvía `null`.

El contenido de `values` no debería ser convertido a cadena de caracteres porque su contenido es una matriz. Podrías usar la propiedad [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/length) para conocer el número de elementos que hay en ella:

```
var values = $('#division').val();
if (values != null || values.length > 0){
    showFields();
}
```

De esta manera cubres cualquier versión de jQuery.

Por otro lado, ese código se ejecutará una única vez durante la carga de la página. Necesitas agregar un evento que se ejecute cada vez que pulses en `Agregar >` (por poner un ejemplo).

Tu código y tu problema ya no es trivial y se vuelve algo complejo en el momento que no nos facilitas más información acerca del origen de los datos, si puedes seleccionar más de un equipo de una o más divisiones o no.

De cualquier manera, has dejado claro que sólo se puede tener una única división activa en todo momento, por lo que ya no necesitas el atributo `multiple`. No es necesario si sólo quieres seleccionar un único elemento a la vez, basta con usar `size` para obtener la misma apariencia visual:

```js
// Simulo _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  /* Precargamos estos objetos del DOM */
  var division = document.getElementById('division');
  var division_sel = document.getElementById('division_sel');
  var equipo = document.getElementById('equipo');
  /* Llamamos a la función que oculta los equipos,
      aunque debería estar oculto por defecto */
  hideFields();
  /* Rellenamos los campos de las divisiones */
  for (var elemento in datos) {
    /* Creamos un objeto "option" */
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    /* Le asignamos los valores "name" y el contenido de texto */
    option.name = elemento;
    option.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(datos[elemento].nombre)
    );
    /* Agregamos el nodo al select */
    division.appendChild(option);
  }
  /* Ahora agregamos el código para agregar elementos de la selección */
  document.getElementById('agregar_division').addEventListener('click', function() {
    /* Limpiamos la cajita de división seleccionada */
    while (division_sel.firstChild) {
      division_sel.removeChild(division_sel.firstChild);
    }
    /* Ahora agregamos el elemento seleccionado */
    for (i = 0; i < division.options.length; i++) {
      if (division.options[i].selected == true) {
        /* Agregamos un nodo clonado del original (con mismo contenido) */
        division_sel.appendChild(division.options[i].cloneNode(true));
        /* Limpiamos el contenido previo de los equipos (debería estar borrado) */
        while (equipo.firstChild) {
          equipo.removeChild(equipo.firstChild);
        }
        /* Y ahora introducimos sus equipos en la caja de abajo */
        for(var elemento in datos[division.options[i].name].equipos) {
          /* Creamos un objeto "option" */
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          /* Le asignamos los valores "name" y el contenido de texto */
          option.name = elemento;
          option.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
              datos[division.options[i].name].equipos[elemento]
            )
          );
          /* Agregamos el nodo al select */
          equipo.appendChild(option);
        }
        /* Mostramos la caja de equipos */
        showFields();
      }
    }
  });
  /* Ahora agregamos el código para quitar elementos de la selección */
  document.getElementById('quitar_division').addEventListener('click', function() {
    /* Limpiamos la cajita de división seleccionada */
    while (division_sel.firstChild) {
      division_sel.removeChild(division_sel.firstChild);
    }
    /* Limpiamos la cajita de equipos */
    while (equipo.firstChild) {
      equipo.removeChild(equipo.firstChild);
    }
    /* Ocultamos el campo de equipos */
    hideFields();
  });
});

function hideFields() {
    /* No uses "parentNode...parentNode", es una mala práctica, se complicará
        mantener el código HTML. Mejor selecciona el nodo exacto que quieras */
    equipo.style.display = "none";
}

function showFields() {
    equipo.style.display = "block";
}

/* Datos de ejemplo */
var datos = {
  'liga_es': {
    nombre: 'Liga Española',
    equipos: {
      'equipo_esp_1': 'Equipo Español 1',
      'equipo_esp_2': 'Equipo Español 2',
      'equipo_esp_3': 'Equipo Español 3',
    },
  },
  'liga': {
    nombre: 'Liga Extranjera',
    equipos: {
      'equipo_ext_1': 'Equipo Extranjero 1',
      'equipo_ext_2': 'Equipo Extranjero 2',
      'equipo_ext_3': 'Equipo Extranjero 3',
    },
  },
};
```

```css
/* Centramos los contenidos en la celda */
table td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Hacemos que los botones ocupen el ancho de la celda */
table button {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="division" size="3" title="División"
          style="width: 143px; overflow: scroll;">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="agregar_division">Agregar &gt;</button>
      <button id="quitar_division">&lt; Quitar</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="division_sel" size="3" title="División Seleccionada"
          style="width: 143px; overflow: scroll;">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Simulamos tres niveles de profundidad para tu campo -->
<div><div><div>
<select id="equipo" size="5"
    title="Equipos seleccionados"
    style="width: 143px; height: 125px; overflow: scroll;">
</select><br/>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: no puedo añadir onchange="comprobar()" porque es una lista de Sharepoint y no puedo modificar el DOM, o eso creo...

Comment: De todos modos no es recomendable poner funciones en los elementos HTML, tú puedes agregar un evento `on. change` directamente en Javascript basándote en el `id` del elemento, así dejas el contenido HTML lo más independiente posible del código Javascript.

Comment: He editado a ver si visualmente se capta la idea. Mi expresion tampoco es muy buena

Comment: ¿Se puede seleccionar más de una división? ¿Los equipos salen arriba o debajo?

Comment: Esta ultima edicion de tu respuesta esta bien pero puedo agregar la liga extranjera y me saldran los 3 equipos extranjeros y puedo agregar la liga española y me saldrian los 3 equipos españoles, es decir, si agrego ambas ligas me tendran que salir los equipos de ambas ligas, en el ejemplo 6

Comment: Por otro lado, no se como llevarlo a la practica en mi ejemplo ya que el DOM o el HTML me lo da sharepoint y no puedo añadir nuevas acciones en el DOM

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor es con `$("#id").val();`.

Te dejo un ejemplo breve:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="miId" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Cafe</option>
    <option value="2">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="3">Coca Cola</option>
    <option value="4">Snacks</option>
    <option value="5">Vino</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="miFuncion();" value="Obtener Valores">
<script>
function miFuncion(){
var values = $('#miId').val();
  if(values == "" || values == null){
  alert("no posee valores");
  }else{
  alert(values);
  }

}//end function

</script>
```

Para validar usa el or `||`,  de esta manera obtienes lo valores por ID y luego validas si son `null` o vacíos.

Comment: cambiado el operador logico. he editado con las modificaciones

Answer (score 1):

Al realizar:

```
document.getElementById('division')
```

Obtienes el objeto DOM de un select, para saber si tiene algun elemento seleccionado, tendrias que consultar su propiedad `.value`. Esta propiedad tiene el primer elemento seleccionado.

Ejemplo:

```js
function divisionChange() {
  var select = document.getElementById('division');
  if (select.value) {
    console.log("llamar a showFields()");
  } else {
    console.log("llamar a hideFields()");
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="division" multiple onchange="divisionChange()">
  <option value="1">Uno</option>
  <option value="2">Dos</option>
</select>
```